# Execute file from maven goal

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I like to integrate compass (https://github.com/Compass/compass/wiki)
in my java project, and I need something to compile .sass files to css without running commands manualy.

So is there a way to execute a file using some maven plugin or goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [exec-maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin

Comment: That's what I was looking form.

Answer (score 0):

The maven-antrun-plugin is the usual practice here, as it allows you to use an ant task to execute whatever. An alternative might be [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GMaven), but I confess that I don't know for sure that it can execute an arbitrary executable.